# Deployment time of wsp in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-package, solution-deployment, registry

I like to enter the deployment time of wsp into registry when we had installed on particular server.

How to get it in code?

Comment: How are you deploying WSP, if you are using powershell script , you can think of adding scripts  to your code for updating registry.

Comment: do you have any code to enter entry in registry on feature activation?

Comment: Are you wanting to schedule the deployment of a WSP or get the time it was deployed?

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the internet.  Look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/09/use-powershell-to-easily-create-new-registry-keys.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705401/how-to-set-system-environment-variable-in-c
It has code examples for setting values in registry.